# Calculus: Absolute Convergence of $ \sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n(\ln(n))^{2/3}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Here is the problem:

> Determine whether the series $$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n(\ln(n))^{2/3}}$$ is absolutely convergent, conditionally convergent, or divergent.

I tried the Ratio Test and the Root Test and they both came out to $L=1$ or *inconclusive*, so now what do I do?

Comment: Integral Test.  Or Cauchy Condensation, but that is not taught as routinely.  It will turn out to be not absolutely convergent. But convergent, sure.

Comment: You could consider using a combination of the $n^{th}$ root test and the comparison test possibly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It converges (alternating series) and you can compare to an integral to test for absolute convergence
$$
\int_2^{\infty}\frac{1}{x}(\log x)^{-2/3}dx=\int_{\log 2}^{\infty} u^{-2/3}du=3u^{1/3}\Bigg|_{\log 2}^{\infty}=\infty
$$

Comment: Quick question: Why is the 1/x on the far left no longer (-1)/x?

Comment: Also, so since the integral test came out to $\infty$ which is not < 1 it means it is not absolutely convergent?

Comment: @StickFigs the integral test (look in your book if you have one) is a way of determining convergence/divergence of a series of positive terms $\sum a_n$ by comparing the series to the area under the graph of a function $f$ with $f(n)=a_n$  (draw a picture thinking of the series geometrically as a bunch of columns with height $a_n$ and width 1 with the base of the column on the interval $[n,n+1]$ or $[n-1,n]$)